# How do I make krusader the default file manager?

Tags: default-programs, krusader

Is it possible to set krusader as the default file manager in ubuntu 13.10?
I tried to defined it in `system settings > details > default applications` but there is nothing about file manager there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

open your terminal with  <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>  and paste this line

```
 sudo mv /usr/bin/nautilus /usr/bin/natilus.back && sudo ln -s /usr/bin/krusader /usr/bin/nautilus
```

Comment: I've done that and it works, but could it provoke the desktop wallpaper to disappear? since then my desktop is black...

Comment: The wallpaper you would like to set in pictures or home dir of your user. And problem occurs not due to this

Answer (score 5):

1) Make a folder in your home directory called bin

```
mkdir ~/bin
```

2) Make a script called Nautilus that executes Dolphin and put it in this folder

```
gedit ~/bin/nautilus
```

3) Then copy this code into it and save

```
#!/bin/bash
exec krusader $@
exit 0
```

This will launch `krusader` every time `nautilus` was to be launched.

Comment: I went with the other answer (because I'm lazy and it was only a one line solution), but now my desktop is black, no more wallpaper. Do you think it's related? Would your solution avoid that issue? How could I undo it in order to do yours?

Comment: Just wanted to add a reminder to Bruno's excellent script to make sure you chmod it to be executable. I'm sure it's second nature for most, but it had me scratching my head for a minute or two.

Answer (score 2):

## Ubuntu 18.04

- If you want to set Nemo as the default file manager, run this command in Terminal:

  ```
  xdg-mime default nemo.desktop inode/directory application/x-gnome-saved-search
  ```
- To revert this enter

  ```
  xdg-mime default nautilus.desktop inode/directory application/x-gnome-saved-search
  ```
- Test it with

  ```
  xdg-open $HOME
  ```

Answer (score 1):

Another place where default file manager is configured (I use Debian 9.8):

```
/usr/share/dbus-1/services/org.freedesktop.FileManager1.service
```

This file is used, for example, Eclipse IDE for run "System Explorer" through a call to `dbus-send`. The original file content looks as follows:

```
[D-BUS Service]
Name=org.freedesktop.FileManager1
Exec=/usr/bin/nautilus --gapplication-service
```

But you must write your own service to replace nautilus to use this config...