# I prefer Thunar as the file manager. How do I keep it?

Tags: gnome, nautilus, default, thunar

Unfortunately, Nautilus is not doing its job the way I prefer. Therefore, I have edited the files /usr/share/applications/nautilus-folder-handler.desktop and /usr/share/spplications/nautilus-home.desktop to both start Thunar instead. This works fine until some update restores the old content in these files. I don't know which update does it, but I am forced to edit the files anew. This happened again today, and I'm getting tired of it. Please, is there a way to keep my preferred file manager, also across updates? Thanks :D

Comment: What happens if you create a copy of those `.desktop` files in your `~/.local/share/applications/` directory and then edit?

Comment: How do you lauch the file manager? Like you, I prefer something non-Nautilus ([PCManFM](https://wiki.lxde.org/en/PCManFM) in my case) and I simply put its (.desktop)icon in my panel and on a short-cut/hotkey, etc. Nautilus is rarely opened and safely ignored.

Comment: Does [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/368996/38585) (or another one in that Q&A) meet your need?

Comment: David - I always use the "Places" top menu item to open the file manager. That way, I can open it regardless of which application is running, full-screen or not.





pomsky - never tried that :)